# Mail trigger in UCM

Tags: webcenter

I have a requirement that mail should be triggered when content is either checked in, checked out or updated.  Currently the workflow is not enabled.  Can someone please suggest how this can this be done?

I tried using workflow criteria, but the mail is getting triggered only for new check-ins.  One further confusion is that the mail is getting triggered before the workflow is being approved, but this should not happen.

Thanks in advance,

Deepthi

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [Subscription](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wcc/WCCAA/GUID-8D705BBA-5398-4803-B435-61D27C58EF93.htm#WCCAA1734)?

> A subscription is a function that notifies users by email when a
>   particular content item has been revised.